# How to display a PNG image with transparent background from .Net in Android?

Tags: android, .net, png, transparency

This is the method I use on `.NET` to create the string that sent to the `android` App, the image is `System.Drawing.Image` type convert in `Bitmap`:

```
Public Shared Function SerializeObject(ByVal objeto As Bitmap) As String        

    Dim bitmapBytes As Byte()
    Dim stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream

    objeto.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
    bitmapBytes = stream.ToArray

    stream.Flush()
    stream.Dispose()

    Dim str1 = Convert.ToBase64String(bitmapBytes)
    Return str1
End Function
```

And this the android method to create the image:

```
public static Bitmap GetObjectBitmap(String str) {
    Bitmap bm;

    try {
       byte [] encodeByte=Base64.decode(str.trim(), Base64.DEFAULT);
       bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);    
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
        bm = null;
    }
    return bm;
}
```

The problem is that the image is displayed in the `ImageView` with a black background instead of transparent.

Comment: i didn't know that **bmp** format has transparency ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saving the image in abmp format, but you need to save it in png format instead.

Change the following line from you code

```
objeto.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
```

To this

```
objeto.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
```